# Is this always true (stochastic independence)?

Tags: probability

> Let $A,B,C,D$ be events in a probability space. Suppose $A\perp \!\!\!\!\!\! \perp B$, $B\perp \!\!\!\!\!\! \perp C$, $C\perp \!\!\!\!\!\! \perp D$.
> It is always true that $$A\perp \!\!\!\!\!\! \perp D$$

This has me totally stumped!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's false. Stochastic independence is not transitive.

Look at the following example (3 events A,B,C)

Consider the experiment of tossing two fair dice. Let A denote the event of an odd total, B the event of an 1 on the first die, and C the event of a 7 total.

We obtain

$$\mathbb{P}[A|B]=\frac{1}{2}=\mathbb{P}[A]$$

$$\mathbb{P}[C|B]=\frac{1}{6}=\mathbb{P}[C]$$

But

$$\mathbb{P}[A|C]=1 \ne \mathbb{P}[A]$$

Thus A and B are independent, the same is true for B and C but it is false for A and C

...try yourself as an exercise to find a couterexample with 4 events